# std::bind to local variable as a value

Tags: c++, lambda, bind, std

Is it a good practice to bind to a value which is a local variable:

```
bool func(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    return a + "abc" == b;
}
```

.........

```
auto str = getRandomString();
auto it = std::find_if(
    vec.begin(), 
    vec.end(), 
    std::bind(func, str, std::placeholders::_1));
```

As `std::bind` return value is a function object the for each local variable it create a new function object? Should I use lambda expression instead?

```
auto it = std::find_if(
    vec.begin(), 
    vec.end(), 
    [str](const std::string& b){return str + "abc" == b;});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should almost always prefer using a lambda over using `std::bind`. Firstly, it does not suffer from potential ambiguity that `std::bind` does; for example:

```
void foo(int a, std::string b);
void foo(Object a, std::string b);

std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, some_string); // Which function is this binding?
```

(Yes, you can fix this, but it is really ugly and requires explicit casts).

Secondly, the lambda version is likely to be faster: in the end it boils down to a normal function call (that can be inlined). `std::bind` generally uses another layer of indirection (a function pointer internally, basically) which hinders inlining.

Finally, you can explicitly tell a lambda how it should store its closure variables (by reference or by value). This can also be done with `std::bind`, but is generally uglier, requiring `std::cref` or `std::ref` wrappers.

Comment: The lambda function written in my code should be called in multiple member functions. So I should duplicate the code of the lambda several times. That's why I thought std::bind might be better with a static function.

Comment: @Narek You could create a variable to store the lambda?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know how to do that considering the variable capturing. And cannot find any example Could you please help?

Comment: @Narek `auto my_lambda_func = [str](const std::string& b){return str + "abc" == b;});`

Comment: @Yuushi I should store as a member variable and not as a local variable.

Comment: @Narek Then you'll need to use `std::function` as a wrapper to store it.

Comment: @Yuushi how to use `std::function` to preserve the capuring of `str` too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345871/store-lambda-function-that-captures-the-scope-variable-as-a-class-member-to-reus

Answer (score 1):

Both create a function object containing a copy of `str`.

The lambda is marginally better, since the function is a member function, which can be called directly. `bind` stores a function pointer, which might require storage, and might have to be called indirectly, depending on how good the optimiser is.

Comment: Different function objects for different `str`s are created?

Comment: @Narek: A different function object for each call to `bind`, or for each lambda expression. Each of your examples creates one function object, then passes it by value to `find_if`, which calls it once for each vector element.

Comment: For lambda I guess for different `str` the same FO is used, what about `std::bind`?

Comment: @Narek: I've no idea what you mean. Each lambda expression, and each call to `bind`, creates a new function object.

Comment: That is what I was asking.