# Store lambda function that captures the scope variable as a class member to reuse

Tags: c++, lambda

In my class lots of methods have such a snippet:

```
std::string str = getSomeStr();

auto it = std::find_if(
vec.begin(), 
vec.end(), 
[str](const std::string& b){return str + "abc" == b;});
```

Therefore, I want to store the lambda function to reuse it. But it captures the `str` from the scope. How I should do that?

Comment: Wait, so do you want to store a closure or not? How about currying the expression?

Comment: it's captured *by copy*, what is your concern? are you aiming to store the lambda object as a pointer to function?

Comment: My problem is that in each methods I should have duplicate of this lambda expression. I want to avoid duplication. How should I do that?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sorry I don't understand what you ask. I just don't what to have 10 times the same `[str](const std::string& b){return str + "abc" == b;}` in my `.cpp` file.

Comment: store it in `std::function<bool(const std::string&)>` data member

Comment: How then it will capture the second string - the `str` which is in the scope? Please show and example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood it right...

```
class MyOperation {
    std::string s;
public:
    MyOperation(std::string s) : s(s) { }

    operator()(const std::string& b) {
        return s + "abc" == b;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::string str = getSomeStr();

auto it = std::find_if(
    vec.begin(), 
    vec.end(), 
    MyOperation(str));
```

You don't have to use the `str` temporary, or make `MyOperation` hold only a `std::string` reference. This depends on what do you want to achieve.

---

of course technically you can do this:

```
auto myOperation(std::string s) { 
    return [s = std::move(s)](const std::string& b) {
        return s + "abc" == b;
    };
}
```

But I don't see the point, frankly.

Comment: Exactly, what I want only I need with a lambda function. Can I avoid writing a functor?

Comment: @Narek I kinda don't get the point. Lambdas are useful because they can be defined in the call site. But you want to define it outside, to make it reusable - what's the problem with making it a functor then?

Comment: I agree with you, but want to understand technically it is possible to not define the functor but ask compiler to do that for us.

Comment: @Narek if you're asking whether there exists *magic* to somehow capture random scope variables (by what, exactly? name?) to your functors that aren't functors, the answer is **no**.

Comment: Don't get angry :) My fault is to try to reuse lambda. Lambda is not for reusing! And you are right, I should use functors! Thanks

Comment: @Narek In retrospective, my tone was too harsh, I apologize, I didn't mean for it to come out as aggresive. I too sometimes miss something like `let ... in` and `where` (from Haskell) in C++, but since what you get are classes, I don't see a reason to not use them. Especially that you can get nice code reuse and inheritance for such functors can actually work quite well.

Comment: No need to apologize at all! :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should capture `s` by value. (in `auto myOperation(...)`)

Comment: @appleapple that should actually be a move capture

Comment: good. I was think about pass by const reference then copy. but move is better.

Answer (score 3):

How about a capture by reference and then assign to that reference before each use:

```
std::string str = getSomeStr();
std::string str2 = getSomeOtherStr();
std::string *captured_str;

auto lambda =  [&captured_str](const std::string* b){return *str + "abc" == b;}

captured_str = &str;
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lambda);
captured_str = &str2;
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lambda);
```